# PDFBox error: "org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer not found" when it is present

Tags: java, maven, pdfbox, bitbucket-server

I am writing a plugin for Bitbucket Server, in which I have to deal with rendering PDFs to images. I use PDFBox for this purpose. I have a `pdfToPng` method that will be called to do the processing and I have modified the PDF renderer similarly to what the Apache examples suggest.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawerParameters;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PDFProcessor {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PDFProcessor.class);

    private static int _colorMode;

    /**
     * Convert a page of a PDF document into a colored PNG
     * @param color color to use, 0 - black, 1- red
     * @param fileName output file
     * @param pdfFile PDF to process
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void pdfToPng(int color, String fileName, File pdfFile) throws IOException{
        _colorMode = color;
        try (PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile)){
            logger.info("Begin PDF to PNG render for " + fileName);
            PDFRenderer renderer = new CustomPdfRenderer(pdfDoc);
            BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0,600);
            logger.info("Making PNG transparent...");
            BufferedImage transparentImage = ImageProcessor.makeTransparent(image,new Color(image.getRGB(0,0)));
            ImageIO.write(transparentImage, "PNG",new File(fileName+".png"));
            logger.info("Image processed successfully, writing to " + fileName + ".png");
        }
    }

    private static class CustomPdfRenderer extends PDFRenderer{
        CustomPdfRenderer(PDDocument document){
            super(document);
        }

        @Override
        protected PageDrawer createPageDrawer(PageDrawerParameters params) throws IOException{
            return new CustomPageDrawer(params);
        }
    }

    private static class CustomPageDrawer extends PageDrawer{
        CustomPageDrawer(PageDrawerParameters params) throws IOException{
            super(params);
        }

        @Override
        protected Paint getPaint(PDColor color) throws IOException{
            if ((color.toRGB() == (Color.BLACK.getRGB() & 0x00FFFFFF)) && (_colorMode == 1)){
                return Color.RED;
            }
            return super.getPaint(color);
        }
    }
}
```

The project is built using Maven, as this is when BitBucket uses for the plugin development. However, when the method is actually called, I get a `ClassNotFound` exceptioni stating:

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/rendering/PDFRenderer
[INFO]  at com.my-plugin.DiffManager.prepareDiff(DiffManager.java:99)
[INFO]  at com.my-plugin.DiffManager.doGet(DiffManager.java:67)
[INFO]  at com.my-plugin.DiffManager.doPost(DiffManager.java:84)
[INFO]  ... 33 common frames omitted
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer not found by com.my-plugin.integrationPlugin [219]
[INFO]  at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
[INFO]  ... 36 common frames omitted
```

As you can see, I have imported the `PDFRenderer` class. My `pom.xml` also contains the correct dependency definition:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.14</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Why can't Java find the `PDFRenderer` class? The other dependencies that are declared in this way never has this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the dependency of `pdfbox` with `<scope>provided</scope>`. Who do you expect to provide this dependency when it is needed? An application container like Tomcat?

I suggest that you delete the `scope` line, so the dependency will be implicitly `compile` scope, which should solve the problem for you.

Please consult also the [Maven scope docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) which say:

- `compile` – This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
- `provided`– This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to do the trick. Since I am new to Maven, the scopes are still a bit confusing. I think in this case it refers to the Atlassian container - but at the same time, I have other packages with the `<provided>` scope and so far I had encountered no problems. Perhaps this calls for some code cleanup.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah check it and if necessary, don't hesitate come back. I'd be glad to help with other Maven-related questions, too. If all for this question and dependency is clear, you could also consider accepting this answer here, to show also to other guys, that it worked.